# Problems during update of an extension in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

While trying to update an extension using `Platform->Update` in the Hybris Administration Console (HAC), I am getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

... and then it is dumping big SQL statements. How to debug this?

Comment: db return part of sql which has error. if this db side error not logged, check db log files. then find this part in whole sql. May be problem is data type on db side.

Comment: Could you post the SQL statement and the database you are using ?